# A Curved/Warped Version of Fubini's Theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, integration, smooth-manifolds, geometric-measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

I will think of  $ \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ as $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m$.

Let  $ V \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ be open and $g:V \to U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+m} $ be a $C^1$ diffeomorphism. For a fixed ${y} \in \mathbb{R}^m$, the image $g(\mathbb{R}^n \times \{y\})$ is an $n$-dimensional $C^1$ manifold, and, similarly, for a fixed ${x}$, the image $g(\{x\} \times \mathbb{R}^m)$ is an $m$-dimensional $C^1$ manifold. Let $\mathcal{H}^n$ and $\mathcal{H}^m$ be, respectively, the Hausdorff measures on these with respect to the intrinsic metric on them induced from $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$. As mentioned in the comments below, they will be different from fiber to fiber, and, for example, it is not true that all these measures are identifiable.

**Original Question:** I wonder if a "Fubini's theorem" can be formulated and proven using integrals on these manifolds directly.** I do NOT wish to pullback to $V$ via $g$,

Edit: Initially I stated "I do not want to contaminate my integral with the Jacobian!" In light of comments below, it will be impossible to bring in some type of Jacobian(S) into picture. Now, it looks obvious: We must take into account how fibers close in or expand away from one another at different neighborhoods. So, now I reiterate my question allowing this:

**Edited Question:** Is there "a Fubini's theorem" that equates an integral over $U$ to the iterated integrals (of the function probably multiplied with some Jaobian of the map $g$) over these fibers -- against their intrinsic Hausdorff measures.**

A cartoon of the sought-for identity will look like: for a continuous real-valued function $ \phi: U \to \mathbb{R}$, 
$$ \int_U \phi \ d\mathcal{L}^{n+m}= \int_{?} \left(\int_{?} \phi(x,y) \cdot Jacobian \ quantities \ from \ g \ d\mathcal{H}^n(x)\right) \ d\mathcal{H}^m(y) \ .$$

**Note:** I seem to have figured out one such formula but will wait longer for possible alternatives or references to known ones, if any exists.

I have the answer here: [Fubini's Theorem on Arbitrary Foliations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350952/fubinis-theorem-on-arbitrary-foliations)

Comment: There is a natural diffeomorphism between $g(\mathbb{R}^n \times \{y_1\})$ and $g(\mathbb{R}^n \times\{y_2\})$ by your mapping. For different values of $y$, the Hausdorff measure $\mathcal{H}^{n}(x)$ is not invariant under this diffeo (in the generic setting). Similarly $\mathcal{H}^m(y)$. In the inner integral you can explicitly write in the $y$ dependence. But you cannot just get rid of the $x$ dependence of the outer integral; hence the Jacobian factor...

Comment: What are the question marks?

Comment: @Piotr Hajlasz: To be determined. See Willie Wong's comment. Ideally the vertical ($m$-dim) fibers for the first and the horizontal fibers for the second integra.

Comment: I have the answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350952/fubinis-theorem-on-arbitrary-foliations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer here: [Fubini's Theorem on Arbitrary Foliations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350952/fubinis-theorem-on-arbitrary-foliations)

$$\int_U f = \int_{U_{\eta_0}} \left(\int_{U_\xi} f(\xi,\eta) \frac{|\det DG_{U_\xi} (\xi,\eta)| \cdot |\det DG_{U_{\eta_0}} (\xi,\eta_0)|}{|\det DG(\xi,\eta)|} \ d\mathcal{H}^m(\eta)\right) \ d\mathcal{H}^n(\xi) \ .$$

Answer (score 7):

Coarea formula will do this for you.  It is a "Fubini formula"  relating the integral of a function $u$ on a  Riemann manifold $(M_0,g_0)$ to  the integrals along the fibers of a smooth map $F:(M_0,g_0)\to (M_1,g_1)$. The map $F$ need not be a submersion.  See [this note](https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Coarea.pdf) for details.

Comment: Though of course the coarea formula requires (the requisite) Jacobian factor

Comment: One cannot avoid Jacobians if we use the Hausdorff measure along the  fivers.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu Thanks for the nice notes, had them already! Do you have an explicit formula for how Jacobian transforms under a ($C^1$-)diffeomorphism that straightens the fibers? Is there a component that catches the distortion along the fibers in addition to the full Jacobian of the diffeomorphism. More precisly: Say you have a $C^1$ map $f:R^m \supset U \to R^n$, m>n, with rank df = n everywhere. You apply a diffeo $ G: V \to U$ (locally) such that $f \circ G:V \to R^n$ becomes a projection. How are the Jacobians (as used in the coarea formula) of $f$ and $f \circ G$ connected?

Comment: @BehnamEsmayli The Jacobian is  a metric  quantity. To get something that is not metric  you need to work with denisties such as in Prop. 9.1.8 of these notes .  https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf

Comment: I don't see how this is a response to my last comment! Is it?

Comment: To see how yhey are related solve the following linear algebra problem. Take a linear map $A:U\to V$, $\dim V\leq \dim U$. Fix an inner product on $V$. Choose inner products $g_0,g_1$ on $U$.  Accordingly you get two adjoint operators $A^{*_i}$ $V\to U$. Next  express how $\det A^{*_0}A$ and $\det A^{*_1}A$ are related. It is not  that simple.

Comment: Please see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this nicely with differential forms: see the chapter on Fubini's theorem in my lecture notes on [Stokes's theorem](https://euclid.ucc.ie/mckay/analysis/analysis.pdf).